# Batch conversion of columns into rows with file name

Tags: awk

I have more than 1000 files(tab limited) and I need to convert all data into one file as like this

example File02

```
Apple01  cpu01  Computer Desktop mouse
Dell1.2  cpu06  keybord printer usb-0.2 cable
Asus0.3  cpu07  Mouse drive Dvd
```

Expected out put

```
File02  Apple01,Dell1.2,Asus0.3  cpu01,cpu06,cpu07 Computer Desktop mouse,keybord printer usb-0.2 cable,Mouse drive Dvd
```

I tired with awk

```
awk -v RS= -v OFS="," -F'\n' '/----/{next}$1=$1'
```

but it just only transposing

Comment: If you need to process multiple files then you should provide at least 2 as your example (3 would be even better but 2 is minimal) to a) demonstrate the problem adequately and b) give us something we can test against to see if a potential solution works or not (something that works for 1 file may not work for multiple).

Comment: Btw the awk script you posted has absolutely nothing to do with the problem you're trying to solve. If you tell us what you were thinking there we can explain where you went off the rails. Also, if your input file contains `----` lines that need to be handled in some way differently from your other lines then there's nothing else in your question to indicate that so the answers you get won't be able to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be what you're looking for, using GNU awk for ENDFILE and tested with 2 copies of the input file in your question:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        a[i] = (i in a ? a[i] "," : "") $i
    }
}
ENDFILE {
    printf "%s", FILENAME
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        printf "%s%s", OFS, a[i]
    }
    print ""
    delete a
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
file1   Apple01,Dell1.2,Asus0.3 cpu01,cpu06,cpu07       Computer Desktop mouse,keybord printer usb-0.2 cable,Mouse drive Dvd
file2   Apple01,Dell1.2,Asus0.3 cpu01,cpu06,cpu07       Computer Desktop mouse,keybord printer usb-0.2 cable,Mouse drive Dvd
```

With other awks you'd do:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
FNR==1 { prt() }
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        a[i] = (i in a ? a[i] "," : "") $i
    }
    fname = FILENAME
}
END { prt() }

function prt(   i) {
    printf "%s", fname
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        printf "%s%s", OFS, a[i]
    }
    print ""
    delete a
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try this `awk`:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="\t"
}
NR==1 {
   for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
      c[i]=$i
   next
}
{
   for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
      c[i]=c[i] "," $i
}
END {
   printf "%s", FILENAME OFS
   for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
      printf "%s", c[i] (i<NF?OFS:ORS)
}
' File02
```

Comment: It is working, but how do I proceed with multiple files

Comment: You wrote this in question `convert all data into one file` and never asked for running this on multiple files. Otherwise change is trivial to run this on multiple files.